# importing date+time data into R

Tags: r, date, time-series

My data are in the format "12.02.2017 18:00:00" where the first digits represent the day (ie 12 February 2017 6:00 PM). When I read the (.csv) data files into R, R treats these as character data. I've tried a bunch of different approaches, none successfully, and most errors seem to revolve around the fact that data are treated as characters and/or unrecognized date/time formatting.

Here's some sample data:

```
tdat <- c("12.02.2017 18:00:00", "12.02.2017 18:00:10", "12.02.2017 18:00:20", "12.02.2017 18:00:30")
```

I'd like to avoid re-formatting in Excel as my data files are very large and it seems that surely there's a faster way to do this R.

Thanks!

Comment: You could start here: `?strptime`.

Comment: What exactly did you try and how didn't it work?

Comment: if you don't care about the time and just want to date you can run `as.Date(tdat, "%d.%m.%Y")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read document of `strptime()` carefully, there is a long list of symbols.

```
tdat <- c("12.02.2017 18:00:00", "12.02.2017 18:00:10", "12.02.2017 18:00:20", "12.02.2017 18:00:30")  
tdat.i <- strptime(tdat, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
tdat.i
```

You could specify time zone if you want.